# Drawing a quad in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have the coordinates of 4 points, and I want to to draw a quad based on those coordinates in opencv! is there in function that can based on those point draw a region! I know that `rect` can do that but I know I'll not always have a rectangle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found and it works ;)

```
cv::fillConvexPoly(covered,cropped,cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
```

were covered is my frame and cropped is the vector of points, and if you don't get a rectangle form try to reorder the vector

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use polygon drawing with `polylines` or `fillPoly` see [drawing functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines) for more information.

Comment: @bkausbebk I found the solution and you'Re right I used cv::fillConvexPoly